# Magento Add complete status into the 'order status' drop down in 'Zero Subtotal Checkout' payment method

Tags: magento

I need to add 'Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE' into status drop down in 'Zero Subtotal Checkout' payment method i system->configuration. And make complete as default value for that payment method. I tried to override the 'Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Order_Status_Newprocessing'. But i am unable to do so. Can anyone please tell me what i need to do.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that, I have made a mistake. Below is the right way;

config.xml

```
<config>
<models>
<adminhtml>
<rewrite>                       
<system_config_source_order_status_newprocessing>My_Module_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Order_Status_Newprocessing</system_config_source_order_status_newprocessing>
</rewrite>
</adminhtml>
</models>
</config>
```

Newprocessing.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Order_Status_Newprocessing extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Order_Status_Newprocessing
{
    protected $_stateStatuses = array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to tackle this issue by creating the file in my local pool. No need to create an extension and the overwrite works like a charm:

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Order/Status/Newprocessing.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Order Statuses source model
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Order_Status_Newprocessing extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Order_Status
{
    protected $_stateStatuses = array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE,
    );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this issue. Firstly, set up the status for downloadable products correctly. Secondly, if the first one is not working, add manually the status as KNKM recommended. I've written an article about it at [my blog](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magento-free-order-with-status-as-complete/). I hope it helps.